# Page title need better descriptions

Tags: bug, new-nav

I know we are still in alpha testing but I've got a lot of tabs open with the new navigation but I can no longer tell which tab is which, they all start with New Questions:

> [image]

I can't tell which tabs are for a specific tag, or for the main page, etc.  Can we get a better description on the title again?